# How to have a clipboard functionality for multiple copy-pasting?

Tags: copy-paste, multitasking

I want to know if there are slots of option in copying:

copy1 copy2

then paste1 paste2

I love surfing many websites but need to login on them. I'm tired of typing every time my email address and password.

Because there is email & password there must be  two or more slots:

1. for the copy-pasting documents
2. slot for email
3. for password
4. for second email account
5. for 2nd extra password

but the password must contain 4pin no. to paste

e.g:

- save as copypaste 1?
- save as copypaste 2?
- save as copypaste 3?
- save as copypaste 4?
- save as link1 --add website link & title
- save as link 2
- add another slot

Comment: What you really want is a [password manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=keepass2android.keepass2android) -- you are using different passwords for every site, right?.

Answer (score 6):

The category of app you are looking for is called Clipboard Manager.
Well, I have been using the app called [Clipboard Everywhere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.clipboard.lite&hl=en) which keeps a history of clipboard items and can be used very easily to recall the items copied before the last copied item.

Alternatively, you can use [Clipper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rojekti.clipper&hl=en)

I recommend **Clipboard Everywhere** as it consumes less ram.
Best of luck.

Comment: For additional alternatives, be welcome to check with my [list of clipboard apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_clipboard) ;)

Comment: Those are good options - is this capability included directly in Android?  I haven't seen such capability built into Android.  EDIT: other than to use like a generic "notepad" and copy/pasting from there.  Generally, I wouldn't want to use an external app for auto-copying anything I copy into its pasteboard (coupled with a password manager, that's asking for trouble, particularly for "shared" or cloud backed clipboard managers).

Answer (score 2):

Use Smart Multi Clipboard, It suits best for your use. Instead of 2-3 multiple copy paste job, this does for more than 50 text items together. It is actually a clipboard manager app that manages all of your copied texts in a stack and allow to paste directly once you click inside a text area.

You can also add your own notes into this. These pre written Pinned notes can be used just as copied items quickly like your address or email/message content.

Get it from Playstore here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cv.copybubble

Comment: Do you have some association with this app, or are you just a happy customer?

Comment: Hi Dan, I think I am the happy customer. But you are free to downvote my answer of you feel the app isn't how I explained or if you don't like it.
PS: I don't have any association with this app, I am just a regular user.

Comment: No, there's no problem. Even if you were the author, that would be fine. We just need it to be clear which case is which, so other visitors can judge whether the suggestion is a genuine recommendation or an advert.

Answer (score -2):

Try LastPass.  Everything you are asking for and miles more secure than the clipboard.
https://lastpass.com

Comment: Hi, thank you for suggesting this service, but since the main question is actually about multiple copy-paste, this answer doesn't fulfill the main requirement since LastPass is a password manager, not a general clipboard manager. When you have 50 rep, you can suggest this as a comment instead, as already done by josh3736. I hope you understand.