# Is there a way I can see or edit clipboard entries in Samsung Galaxy Tab S?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, copy-paste, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-10.5

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab S running Lollipop stock update (8.6 Wi-fi only).

I need to be able to visually reference what is being stored for the clipboard for a variety of reasons.

My Galaxy Tab 7.0 Plus had an "advanced clipboard"  (I think that's what it was called). It gave the user the ability to edit, delete or use several separate entries with multiple formats (.txt, .jpg). I found it too be the most useful of Samsung's bloatware!

Is there anyway or anything I could do or add to gain similar functionality?

I don't like not being able to access, edit, or delete the contents of the clipboard without turning cartwheels, metaphorically of course.

Comment: See if this helps: [How to have a clipboard functionality for multiple copy-pasting?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/114662)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

native clipboard which used to use Xposed to seamlessly integrate into the system (it was accessed by either the system's paste button or the selection menu). However it was now updated and uploaded to play store, the major update is that it no longer requires Xposed nor root, but it's still seamlessly integrated into the system. By simply double tapping a text filed the clipboard will open,so no notification or distracting floating buttons. Also the selected text from the clipboard gets automatically pasted.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dhm47.nativeclipboard

^^The app only Got published last week to the store . I think it's a breakthrough in the clipboards for Android

Comment: exactly what I needed - or maybe not I almost rooted this thing as per your previous post...yours truly but still not brave~~~~~

Answer (score 1):

I rooted my phone and installed Xposed Framework. Then I installed the module, [Native Clipboard](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.dhm47.nativeclipboard).

Here is the screenshot when it's in use:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: native clipboard]

Comment: Exactly what I "want" to do. I have a disease I call 'ROOT PARANOIA' , It could be fatal...Exposed Framework looks like exactly what I would like to use.  Samsung has so secretly limited the hardware this tablet uses with it's additions to t the software...  I'm going to try and devolope the courage to go thru and Root..  Do you know offhand any Q&A forum (nicer than XDA) that could answer some questions about the means and consequences of rooting this device?